# Instance created in db but not showed in page. Test cleaning in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, database-cleaner

I'm trying to clean my db between specs. So I decided to use the popular gem database_cleaner.
The problem now is that when I create a new instance of a model with FactoryGirl, it is created but not showed in the page.

Here is my spec_helper:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'pry'
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.order = :random
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  config.before(:each, type: :feature) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
  config.before { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
end
```

And the simple test I'm trying to run is this one:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'designs' do
  feature 'editing designs' do
    before(:each) { visit designs_path}
    given!(:design){ create(:design)}

    scenario "from the designs index" do
      binding.pry
      expect(page).to have_content("Ninja Crane")
    end
  end
end
```

I use binding.pry to check the number of designs and see the page. The result is that the design is being created correctly but is not being showed in the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably you are visiting the page before creating the object

Comment: I added a sleep and the same happens. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: It is not a matter of sleeping.Why should that solve your problem? Place a `binding.pry` inside the block `before(:each) { visit designs_path}` and check if at that moment the `designs` table contains data

Comment: You are totally right. That solved my problem. I just had to change the order between visit and given!. Anyway, I don't understand it. I thought it would have visit the page, create the object and then run the scenario in which I ask to content something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that `given!` is just an alias for `let!` and `scenario` is just an alias for `it`. These are [defined by Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2679de1478890b0a8d1f7c0cd3e3f3865e04cde0/lib/capybara/rspec/features.rb).

In RSpec, `let!` use `before` [under the hood](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/0c70d634bb91622ba3fab92fac03574e94466c1a/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L194). Each `before` block is run in order of definition. This means that, if you define a `before(:each)` block before a `let!` block, you're telling RSpec to run the `let!` block after the `before(:each)` block. In this case, you're creating a design after visiting the designs path.

All `before` blocks after evaluated before `it` blocks. This is why you were able to see the record in the database in your `binding.pry` statement.

I'd recommend putting all of your `given!` definitions at the top, to make sure they are defined before evaluating any of your specs.

I'd also moving the exercise phase of the test (`visit design_path`) into `scenario` blocks, as using `before` makes it harder to tell what you're actually testing and makes it more likely that the test runs in a different order than you're expecting.